# This is my Product.js file where is causing an issue

Tags: reactjs

This is my Product.js file where is causing an issue

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import products from "../products";

const Product = ({match}) => {
  const product = products.find((item) => {
    return item._id === match.params.id;
  });
  return <div>{product.name}</div>;
};

export default Product;
```

my app.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Product from "./Pages/Product";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <Header />
        <main className="py-3">
          <Container>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
              <Route path="/product/:id" element={<Product />} />
            </Routes>
          </Container>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I also tried changing match.params.id to Number or ParseInt(match.params) and still got an error...

I know this is very simple but I'm stuck here and can't continue... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try console logging match in the product component

Answer (score 0):

You don´t pass any props to Product component.

Try this.

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"
// below the Product component
const { id } = useParams()
const product = products.find((item) => {
return item._id === id;
});
```

useParams take the params of the router, so, you pass a id in it.

if you do console.log(match) its return undefined.